# PSF with Richardson–Lucy algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Normally with the Richardson–Lucy algorithm , we use only the PSF?
i found this code which use a PSF and a reversed PSF [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854312/how-does-richardson-lucy-algorithm-work-code-example/48240848#48240848)
please i want to know how the spatial reversal of the PSF works and what it's for?

```
PSF_HAT = PSF(end:-1:1,end:-1:1); % spatially reversed psf
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution) on the Richardson-Lucy algorithm gives an alternative formulation that uses the spatial reversal:

> and p hat is the flipped point spread function,

This allows the algorithm to be expressed in terms of two convolutions, one with p and one with p hat.

Comment: thank you for your answer but why we do need to express the algorithm with two deconvolution? i still don't find the utility of p HAT